On the output of multi-column environment with 3 columns and 4 lines
The following document is a multicolumn having three columns:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
a

b

c

d
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

Why the output is a 2 times 2 square like
a  c
b  d

rather than "3+1",
like
a c d
b

?
